# Can't find Spark Submit when using Spark shell

Tags: apache-spark

I installed spark and am trying to run a file 'train.py' in the directory, '/home/xxx/Desktop/BD_Project', in shell using the following command:
`$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit /home/xxx/Desktop/BD_Project/train.py > output.txt`

My teammates who used the same page that I did for spark installations have no problem when running this. However, it throws up the following error for me:
`bash: /bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory`

Comment: You have to set `SPARK_HOME` . Can you run `echo $SPARK_HOME` , and check if it's pointing to the spark installation directory ?

Comment: @Sanket9394 when i run ```echo $SPARK_HOME``` it doesn't return anything. How do i point it to the spark installation directory?

Comment: go the Spark folder that you would have downloaded and unzipped.  Let's the location is `User/abc/spark_2.11` . The run `SPARK_HOME=User/abc/spark_2.11`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your SPARK_HOME to where your spark is installed, typically its in `/usr/local/spark/bin/bin/spark-submit`

Before you set it make sure where spark is installed by going to the directory.

You can set it like this before running your command :

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark/bin/bin/spark-submit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are homebrew user, setting your SPARK_HOME to
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/libexec"`
would solve. Sorry for too late responding. Hoping this would help someone with this odd error.